# "Слишком стар для переноса"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, причины-закрытия

Если попытаться закрыть вопрос, который был задан больше двух месяцев назад ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/419149/178576)), то в появившемся диалоговом окне второй пункт звучит как (обратите внимание на текст в скобках):

```
не по теме, потому что… (слишком стар для переноса)
```

Но если выбрать этот пункт, то в *следующем* открывшемся диалоге нет никаких упоминаний про «старость».

**Обновление**

Как пояснил в комментариях `Nofate`, текст «слишком стар для переноса» означает: «слишком стар для переноса на другой сайт сети *se*» и призван объяснить отсутствие соответствующего пункта в *следующем* диалоге.

Мне кажется, текущая формулировка не даёт ясного понимания вложенного в неё смысла и требует изменения.

Поступило такое предложение от `VladD`:

> слишком стар для переноса на другой сайт StackExchange

Я бы предложил ещё добавить в начале два слова «а также», чтобы пункт звучал так:

> не по теме, потому что… (а также слишком стар для переноса на другой сайт StackExchange)

Comment: Пока вопрос не "слишком стар для переноса" в списке опций есть вариант - "перенести на другой сайт сети SE". Когда вопрос "слишком стар" - данный пункт пропадает.

Comment: к ХэшКоду отношения не имеет

Comment: @Nofate, у меня такого пункта при закрытии вопроса по приведённой ссылке — нет. могу скриншот приложить или добавить все пункты текстом в тело вопроса: там четыре пункта.

Comment: @Nofate, добавил текст четырех имеющихся пунктов.

Comment: Перечитайте мой первый комментарий. Да, такого пункта нет, потому что пост по ссылке "слишком стар для переноса". Если бы он был посвежее - был бы вариант "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"

Comment: Таким образом надпись "“слишком стар для переноса” объясняет отсутствие варианта "перенести"

Comment: возможно, тогда стоит написать `(слишком стар для переноса на другой сайт StackExchange)`?

Comment: @VladD, мне тоже кажется, что тектс требует переформулировки, ибо способен ввести в заблуждение.

Comment: @VladD, было бы здорово

Comment: А куда вообще можно перенести вопрос на русском языке? на russian.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, иногда вопросы пишут на английском. их обычно закрывают под разными предлогами, а логичнее было бы перенести на подходящий сайт.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin никогда бы не  подумал, что на ru.so спросят на английском. Видать, бывает.

Comment: @VladD: использовал ваш вариант.

Answer (score 2):

Как и предлагалось полгода назад, дополнил строку:

[Tx:2620](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40264399?key=658e278eaa0bc0136306e27c30a10c56)

> не по теме, потому что… (слишком стар для переноса на другой сайт Stack Exchange)

Можно воспроизвести например на этом вопросе: [Фильтрация ListView из EditText](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/427334/181472)

Comment: вижу старый вариант.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: да, он там будет до следующего обновления базы строк.