# "Слишком стар" в очереди на закрытие

Tags: дефект

Поймал баг в очереди на закрытие.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/268381
сам вопрос [Аккаунт разработчика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/755729/%d0%90%d0%ba%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%bd%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Кнопка закрыть скрин [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думаю это "затерялась" старая текстовка. Не первый раз это сообщение вижу. Странно, но при переходе не по теме - нету ответки что выбрали. Иногда есть.

Возможно я таки поймал баг о котором тут написано
["Слишком стар для переноса"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/567/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0)  за день таких из 20 штуки 2-3 ловлю.

Возможно фразу "Слишком стар" я не до конца понял.. но баг ещё в том, что при переходе "не потеме", обычно видно какой из ответов тут выбрали, тут почему-то нету... Возможно выбрали "Другое" ну... не думаю что за другое так часто голосуют...

Я разобрался что **это не дефект**, а недопонимание работы интерфейса. Очередь увидел недавно. По поводу менять ли надпись - думаю предложивший должен создать новый вопрос. У меня предложений пока что нету.

Comment: Поймаю ещё - добавлю ссылки. Или вопрос может закрываться "не по теме" автоматом - тогда пусто?

Comment: Да вроде нет бага. На сайтах SE недавно заданные вопросы могут переноситься на другой сайт, к тематике которого они больше подходят. Если вопрос старый, он вместо переноса просто закрывается.

Comment: Когда не видно, какую причину выбрали - скорее всего, потому что тревогу на закрытие нажимал участник с <3000 репы

Comment: Что-то я так и не понял, в чём предполагаемый баг...

Comment: @Qwertiy Что означает фраза "Слишком стар", ведь причины такой нету, обычно пишется не по теме потому что - и одна из тем закрытия. Например - *"не по теме потому что вопрос вызван проблемой которая больше..."* Ведь вопрос даже не предлагали перенести на другой сайт, скорее всего перенос раньше был.

Comment: @nick_n_a, она означает, что вопрос нельзя перенести на другой сайт, т. к. он слишком старый. Одна из причин во вложенном списке - _"В сети Stack Exchange есть другой сайт, более подходящий для этого вопроса."_

Comment: Понял, это дополнение к тому, что б дизаблить последний пункт. Да вижу... вопрос с того года, и правда старый. Позже попробую аккуратно в ответе изложить.

Comment: Это не баг, но если перевод можно понять настолько неправильно, есть смысл подумать над альтернативой. Ничего сопоставимой длины пока в голову не приходит :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *(слишком стар для переноса на другой сайт Stack Exchange)* является подсказкой, **a не багом** (как я предполагал), что в подменю нельзя будет выбрать пункт *"В сети Stack Exchange есть другой сайт, более подходящий для этого вопроса."*. Появляется сообщение редко, при закрытии вопросов заданных большое время назад (например в 2017 году как данный), т.к. таких вопросов не много. Формулировка и причины утверждены тут ["Слишком стар для переноса"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/567/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0?noredirect=1&lq=1])
2. Отсутствие синего квадрата, означает что  тревогу на закрытие нажимал участник с <3000 репутации, поэтому не показано голоса за закрытие.