# "Слишком стар для переноса" - куда-то делся новый перевод текста

Tags: дефект, локализация, причины-закрытия

Раньше (7 лет назад) был текст "[(слишком стар для переноса)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/567/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0)".

По итогам обсуждения его изменили на "[(слишком стар для переноса на другой сайт StackExchange)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7438/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5)":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А сейчас опять написано "слишком стар для переноса":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обновления в SO похожи на мои попытки разобраться с GitHub Desktop - старое случайно накладывается на новый и потом давай, разбирайся как все было. :) Я это к чему? Начал замечать ошибки которые были исправлены в прошлом. Как к примеру [этот](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKs6D.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обновил [перевод](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14523). Будет доступно в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2023.2.22.43252

К сожалению, в traducir не видно старых переводов, как это было в transifex.

Выглядит так, что текущая строка вообще никогда не содержала в переводе "на другой сайт Stack Exchange" (самый верхний перевод сделан в составе текущего случая):

> [image: transifex]

Строка из [старого сообщения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2440/176217) сейчас не обнаруживается вовсе по ключу. Похоже, что ключи (или вся база строк целиком) обновились в какой-то момент (ориентировочно "Mon, Apr 13, 2020 2:39 PM") и подхватились какие-то доступные переводы.

Comment: а как так получилось? Они что ли заменили одну строку на другую точно такую же?

Comment: @Эникейщик обновил сообщение.